# Convert HQL query into SQL in Java logs

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a sample query like the following

```
String hql = "from Stock s where s.stockCode = :stockCode";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277")
.list();
```

the result is a list like I expect it to be but I want to know how I can sysout the sql query in my Tomcat logs before the query is executed. Can I do it at the code level as opposed to setting a property in log4j or hibernate config?

In this case, I am looking for an output like

```
select * from Stock s where s.code = 123;
```

Answer (score 3):

To access SQL at the code level, you can use [the datasource proxy library](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) with a listener.

You can find the example of the datasource proxy and its listener at my github repo [jpa-puzzles](https://github.com/pwegrzynowicz/jpa-puzzles/tree/master/src/test/java/com/yonlabs/jpa/puzzles/config).

However, if you only want to see the sql-s with bound parameters (`show-sql` shows only sql-s **without** bound parameters), it's easier to use a hibernate configuration:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: Does this go in the log4j property file?

Comment: Also what if I don't have log4j in my project what do I do?

Comment: Hibernate tries to choose the logger implementation used in a project, so it usually is enough to configure it in your logger of choice. 

Those lines from my answer were configured in a spring-boot application properties file for slf4j logger.